# How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to update Book table and Stock table at the same time using a single query. Because ISBN_No in Book table is equal to ISBN_No in stock table. I would like to know how to put below query inside of the existing update statement.

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET Table_A.ISBN_No = Table_B.ISBN_No,
FROM TBL_Book AS Table_A
INNER JOIN TBL_Stock AS Table_B ON Table_A.ISBN_No = Table_B.ISBN_No
WHERE Table_A.ISBN_No = 'datagridview column name'
```

Comment: you can't update 2 tables in the same command

Comment: Usually when you need to do stuff like that you create a Stored Procedure and do all your logic in there so you only have to call the Stored Procedure in your C# code and not have to worry about multiple updates inside the C# code, the Stored Procedure does all that

Comment: You could create a crazy trigger to update the second table after the first - it would be hacky because you'd have to make sure it quit unless fired for your specific updates.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong...this question is very confusingly worded. Can you please clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by *put following query inside of the sql command*? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Brad is right. This should be done via a stored procedure. I'd add that both update statements should be wrapped in an explicit transaction to guarantee that either both or neither updates happen together.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update 2 tables at once with a single `update` query.

If you need to update 2 tables atomically, you can use a transaction:

```
begin tran

update Table_A
set Table_A.ISBN_No = ...

update Table_B
set Table_B.ISBN_No = ...

commit
```

Note that you can bundle this update together into a stored procedure.  If you are performing this update query as part of the [IDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx) commands in a .NET application, you could use a stored procedure as the command and passing in the ISBN number as a parameter to the procedure.

Also, note that [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ensures that an error during one of these statements aborts your transaction and returns an error immediately.  Otherwise, if the Table_A update fails, the Table_B update will like proceed outside of the transaction (depending on error severity).

If there is a [foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that relates Table_B.ISBN_No to Table_A.ISBN_No, and the foreign key is set to `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, the updating the Table_A.ISBN_No will automatically update Table_B.ISBN_No.